# Does IntelliJ IDEA support Kotlin code style import layouts?

Tags: intellij-idea, kotlin

I want my Kotlin import statements to be ordered according to the same rules as with Java ("Editor" → "Code Style" → "Java" → "Imports" → "Import Layout"), but it seems like IDE ignores them completely in Kotlin sources files. Also, I didn't find similar settings for Kotlin (there's no "Import Layout" on "Imports" tab).

Is there any way to have them? (IntelliJ IDEA 2018.3.5 Ultimate Edition)

Comment: You should post is a bug on a https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is currently not supported (as of Kotlin 1.3.20). There's an [open feature request](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-10974) for this functionality; you can vote for it.